# mobile ocr sample code

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, ocr

I was wondering if you can give me sample (or snippet) code in OCR for Mobile Phones because i need to have an idea how to start my project. i know how to code it for the use  in desktop PC's but my partner told me that mobile phones has a different platform. We are planning to use .net for mobile on this one.. hope you can help me..:)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there isn't much for C#/.NET, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745/open-source-windows-mobile-ocr-library).  If you have written OCR code yourself using C#, it might work as is on the Compact Framework, or it might be made workable with minor modifications.  The Compact Framework is a subset of the full .NET framework, so usually code written specifically for CF will run in regular Windows, but code written for Windows may or may not run in CF, depending upon what functionality has been utilized.

Your partner is sort of right, but there are lots of different platforms for mobile device development, and .NET is definitely one of them (and a good one at that).